# PHP Query sets only 1 result in var

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which returns only 1 result while it should have been a lot more. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT technischcontact FROM klanten WHERE technischcontact !=''; "))
{
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
     {
         $bcc = $row['technischcontact'];
         $bcc .= '; ';
      }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, `$bcc .= '; '` should (probably) be throwing you a parse error.

Comment: You're redefining `$bcc` in every iteration, so that it'll be overwritten every time.

Comment: we'd also need to see the db schema and values.

Comment: I had to roll the question back. We don't know if that was a bad paste or not and the OP should have addressed this themselves.

Comment: I made an error in copying the code, the ; should indeed be behind $bcc .= '; '
I apologize

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting `$bcc` each time with `$bcc = $row['technischcontact'];`.  Try building an array in the loop:

```
$bcc[] = $row['technischcontact'];
```

Then implode at the end:

```
$bcc = implode('; ', $bcc);
```

Comment: let's cover the probable parse error in the answer also. My comment could suddenly disappear for some weird reason.

Comment: OK, he said it was returning one result so I assumed a paste or typing error.

Comment: yeah, that could have just been a bad paste.

Comment: Someone else edited and I rolled it back. See my comment under the question.